# Angular ui.router Sub-States not working properly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have some states setup like this:

```
.state('view-course', {
      url: "/view-course",
      templateUrl: "views/viewCourse.html"
    })
    .state('view-course.viewBlockContent', {
      url: "/:courseid/:blockid",
      templateUrl: "views/viewBlockContent.html",
      controller: function($stateParams, $scope, $rootScope) {
        $scope.params = $stateParams;
        $rootScope.blockParameters = $stateParams;
      }
    })
    .state('view-course.viewBlockContent.question', {
      url: "/:questionid",
      templateUrl: "views/questionTemplate.html",
      controller: function($stateParams, $scope, $rootScope) {
        $scope.params = $stateParams;
        $rootScope.questionParameters = $stateParams;
      }
    })
    .state('view-course.viewBlockContent.report', {
      url: "/report",
      templateUrl: "views/goalReport.html",
      controller: function($stateParams, $scope, $rootScope) {
        $scope.params = $stateParams;
        $rootScope.questionParameters = $stateParams;
      }
    })
```

The problem is happening with the `view-course.viewBlockContent.question` and `view-course.viewBlockContent.report` areas, I am referencing the report sub-view like this in my HTML:

```
<a ui-sref="view-course.viewBlockContent.report">REPORT IN</a>
```

When I click on the `REPORT IN` it actually loads the `questionTemplate.html` rather than the `goalReport.html` the weird thing is that the URL structure appends the `/report` or `/:questionid` stuff correctly but it loads the first file (for example if I move the report state before the question state it loads the `goalReport.html` file instead.

Comment: Could you provide a working Plunkr for this? 

Also have you considered using an `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/defaultState')` to capture invalid URLs? Always a great practice.

Comment: I'm already using the otherwise catch